# Detect a pattern in a column with R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to calculate how many times a person moved from one job to another. This can be calculated every time the Job column has this pattern `1 -> 0 -> 1`.

In this example, it happened one rotation:

```
Person Job
  A     1
  A     0
  A     1
  A     1
```

In this another example, person B had one rotation as well.

```
Person Job
  A     1
  A     0
  A     1
  A     1
  B     1
  B     0
  B     0 
  B     1
```

Whats would be a good approach to measure this pattern in a new column 'rotation', by person ?

```
    Person Job  Rotation
      A     1      0
      A     0      0
      A     1      1
      A     1      1
      B     1      0
      B     0      0
      B     0      0
      B     1      1
```

Comment: Why is `Rotation[4] == 1`?

Comment: Because it is cumulative. Every row represents a semester. It means, during 2 years, the person A rotated 1 time

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to capture a group with `101` and count it as a 1. so you use a `pattern="(?<=1)0+(?=1)"` where for all zeros, check whether they are preceeded by 1 and also succeeded by a 1

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
   group_by(Person)%>%
   mutate(Rotation=str_count(accumulate(Job,str_c,collapse=""),"(?<=1)0+(?=1)"))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Person [3]
   Person   Job Rotation
   <fct>  <int>    <int>
 1 A          1        0
 2 A          0        0
 3 A          1        1
 4 A          1        1
 5 B          1        0
 6 B          0        0
 7 B          0        0
 8 B          1        1
 9 C          0        0
10 C          1        0
11 C          0        0
12 C          1        1
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `lag` with `default = 0` and count cumulative sum of condition when value changes from `0` to `1`. Just subtract `1` from the `cumsum` to get the rotation.

The solution using `dplyr` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(Rotation = cumsum(lag(Job, default = 0) == 0 & Job ==1) - 1) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   Person Job Rotation
# 1      A   1        0
# 2      A   0        0
# 3      A   1        1
# 4      A   1        1
# 5      B   1        0
# 6      B   0        0
# 7      B   0        0
# 8      B   1        1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text ="
Person Job
A     1
A     0
A     1
A     1
B     1
B     0
B     0 
B     1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Rotation := +(grepl("101", do.call(paste0,
                       shift(Job, 0:.N, fill = 0)))), Person]
df
#    Person Job Rotation
# 1:      A   1       0
# 2:      A   0       0
# 3:      A   1       1
# 4:      A   1       1
# 5:      B   1       0
# 6:      B   0       0
# 7:      B   0       0
# 8:      B   1       0
# 9:      C   0       0
#10:      C   1       0
#11:      C   0       0
#12:      C   1       1
```

---

A `base R` option would be

```
f1 <- function(x) Reduce(paste0, x, accumulate = TRUE)
df$Rotation <- with(df, +grepl("101", ave(Job, Person, FUN = f1)))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Person = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4L),
                 Job = as.integer(c(1,0,1,1,
                                    1,0,0,1,
                                    0,1,0,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that if a person starts unemployed,
the first job they get doesn't count as rotation.
In that case:

```
library(dplyr)

rotation <- function(x) {
    # this will have 1 when a person got a new job
    dif <- c(0L, diff(x))
    dif[dif < 0L] <- 0L
    if (x[1L] == 0L) {
        # unemployed at the beginning,
        # first job doesn't count as change from one to another
        dif[which.max(dif)] <- 0L
    }
    # return
    cumsum(dif)
}

df <- data.frame(Person = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4L),
                 Job = as.integer(c(1,0,1,1,
                                    1,0,0,1,
                                    0,1,0,1)))

df %>%
    group_by(Person) %>%
    mutate(Rotation = rotation(Job))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Person [3]
   Person   Job Rotation
   <fct>  <int>    <int>
 1 A          1        0
 2 A          0        0
 3 A          1        1
 4 A          1        1
 5 B          1        0
 6 B          0        0
 7 B          0        0
 8 B          1        1
 9 C          0        0
10 C          1        0
11 C          0        0
12 C          1        1
```