# Detect and subset on a pattern in a column vector in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

As an extension of the question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178870/detect-a-pattern-in-a-column-with-r), I am looking to flag instances of and subset on a pattern of values in a column vector grouped by > UserID. The pattern is "0,1,0." There are two additional aspects to take into account:

1) As presented in the example data below, I'll need to contend with NA values. The NA values are substantive and need to be maintained.

2) In the case of a pattern of 0,1,0,1,0, I would like to count both instances of 0,1,0 (i.e., allowing the middle zero to count in both instances).

I've tried variations on the approaches offered in the linked post. The issue that I haven't been able to fix is that in those instances once a UserID was flagged, it carried through the remainder of the observations for that UserID. I'd like to flag only the instances of 0,1,0.

Example Data:

```
df <- data.frame(UserID = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 9L),
                  Job = as.integer(c(NA,0,1,0,NA,1,0,1,0,
                                    1,0,1,0,1,0,NA,1,0,
                                    NA,0,1,NA,0,1,0,1,NA)))
```

Code used:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(UserID)%>%
   mutate(Pattern=str_count(accumulate(Job,str_c,collapse=""),"010"))
```

Result of Code:

```
  UserID   Job Pattern
   <fct>  <int>   <int>
 1 A         NA      NA
 2 A          0      NA
 3 A          1      NA
 4 A          0      NA
 5 A         NA      NA
 6 A          1      NA
 7 A          0      NA
 8 A          1      NA
 9 A          0      NA
10 B          1       0
11 B          0       0
12 B          1       0
13 B          0       1
14 B          1       1
15 B          0       1
16 B         NA      NA
17 B          1      NA
18 B          0      NA
19 C         NA      NA
20 C          0      NA
21 C          1      NA
22 C         NA      NA
23 C          0      NA
24 C          1      NA
25 C          0      NA
26 C          1      NA
27 C         NA      NA
```

Expected Result:

```
  UserID   Job   Pattern
   <fct>  <int>   <int>
 1 A         NA      0
 2 A          0      1
 3 A          1      1
 4 A          0      1
 5 A         NA      0
 6 A          1      0
 7 A          0      1
 8 A          1      1
 9 A          0      1
10 B          1      1
11 B          0      1
12 B          1      1
13 B          0      1
14 B          1      1
15 B          0      1
16 B         NA      0
17 B          1      0
18 B          0      0
19 C         NA      0
20 C          0      0
21 C          1      0
22 C         NA      0
23 C          0      1
24 C          1      1
25 C          0      1
26 C          1      0
27 C         NA      0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. Because your pattern is relatively short, I just hard coded it into the conditional statements.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(UserID = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 9L),
                  Job = as.integer(c(NA,0,1,0,NA,1,0,1,0,
                                    1,0,1,0,1,0,NA,1,0,
                                    NA,0,1,NA,0,1,0,1,NA)))
df %>%
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  mutate(Pattern = case_when(
    Job == 0 & lead(Job) == 1 & lead(Job, 2) == 0 ~ 1,
    Job == 0 & lag(Job) == 1 & lag(Job, 2) == 0 ~ 1,
    Job == 1 & lead(Job) == 0 & lag(Job) == 0 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
  ))
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#> # Groups:   UserID [3]
#>    UserID   Job Pattern
#>    <chr>  <int>   <dbl>
#>  1 A         NA       0
#>  2 A          0       1
#>  3 A          1       1
#>  4 A          0       1
#>  5 A         NA       0
#>  6 A          1       0
#>  7 A          0       1
#>  8 A          1       1
#>  9 A          0       1
#> 10 B          1       0
#> # … with 17 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach (not very efficient) where I collapse `Job` with `paste` and search for the patterns using regex. Then split it back out into elements of a vector:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Pattern = paste(Job, collapse = '-') %>%
           str_replace_all('(0(?=-1-0)|(?<=0-)1(?=-0)|(?<=0-1-)0)', '2') %>%
           str_split(pattern = '-') %>% .[[1]] %>%
           {if_else(. == '2', 1, 0)})
```

With Base R:

```
string <- paste(df$Job, collapse = '-')
pattern <- strsplit(gsub('(0(?=-1-0)|(?<=0-)1(?=-0)|(?<=0-1-)0)', '2', 
                         string, perl = TRUE), split = '-')[[1]]
df$Pattern <- ifelse(pattern == '2', 1, 0)
```

**Output:**

```
   UserID Job Pattern
1       A  NA       0
2       A   0       1
3       A   1       1
4       A   0       1
5       A  NA       0
6       A   1       0
7       A   0       1
8       A   1       1
9       A   0       1
10      B   1       1
11      B   0       1
12      B   1       1
13      B   0       1
14      B   1       1
15      B   0       1
16      B  NA       0
17      B   1       0
18      B   0       0
19      C  NA       0
20      C   0       0
21      C   1       0
22      C  NA       0
23      C   0       1
24      C   1       1
25      C   0       1
26      C   1       0
27      C  NA       0
```